# How can I modify from C# the value of an element which is define in a XAML DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I created a "WPF Application Project" in Visual Studio 2013.

I opened the "MainWindow.xaml" file and I wrote the following XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="TestProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AlphaDataTemplate">
        <Label
            Name="LabelInDataTemplate"
            Content="Good morning!" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ContentPresenter
        Name="MyContentPresenter"
        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource AlphaDataTemplate}" />
    <Button
        Name="MyButton"
        Click="MyButton_OnClick"
        Content="Change the content of the Label in the DataTemplate"
        Width="320"
        Height="30" />
</Grid>
```

In this XAML file I created a "DataTemplate" which corresponds to the key "AlphaDataTemplate". The DataTmplate contains just one label with the name "LabelInDataTemplate" where I have hardcoded the "Good morning!" string in the "Content" attribute of the label.

Then I use created a "ContentPresenter" with the name "MyContentPresenter" and I pass as content the "DataTemplate" I previously created (AlphaDataTemplate).

As next step, I created a "Button" with the name "MyButton" and I have set a "Click" event called "MyButton_OnClick"

So far so good...!

The question comes now and actually in C# in the code behind file "MainWindow.xaml.cs". See the code below:

```
using System.Windows;
```

namespace TestProject
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

```
    }
    private void MyButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LabelInDataTemplate.Content = "Bye!";   // <-- Tha does not work.
    }
}
```

}

In this C# code behind file you can see the definition of the "Click" (MyButton_OnClick) event of the Button (MyButton) which appears in XAML.

What I am trying to do in this "Click" event, is to change the value of the "Content" of the "Label" (LabelInDataTemplate) which is in the DataTemplate (AlphaDataTemplate).

Unfortunately, that does not work.

I cannot actually access the "Name" (LabelInDataTemplate) of the "Label", because it is contained in the "DataTemplate" (AlphaDataTemplate)

If anyone has any idea, how could I modify from C# the value of an element which is define in a XAML DataTemplate, please give me feedback. I would really appreciate it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly oppose your method of changing the content of label via DataTemplate, However your requirement is possible, but very subtle.

Code

```
private void MyButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var alphaDataTemplate = this.Resources["AlphaDataTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
    var label = alphaDataTemplate.FindName("LabelInDataTemplate", MyContentPresenter) as Label;
    label.Content = "It Works";
}
```

Comment: The solution you posted works perfectly! Thank you very much!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Please learn MVVM and use proper DataBinding for this purpose. For sake of solving this problem:

1. Implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface on your Window class and Define string property like below

   ```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       public MainWindow()
       {
           InitializeComponent();

           DataContext = this;

       }

       public string _contentMsg;
       public string ContentMsg
       {
           get { return _contentMsg; }
           set 
           { 
               _contentMsg = value;
               RaisePropertyChanged("ContentMsg");
           }
       }

       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
       private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
       {
           if(PropertyChanged !=null)
           {
               PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
           }
       }
   ```
2. In your xaml bind the ContentPresenter and update your DataTemplate label like

   ```
   <ContentPresenter
   Name="MyContentPresenter"
   Content = "{Binding ContentMsg}"
   ContentTemplate="{StaticResource AlphaDataTemplate}" />

   <DataTemplate x:Key="AlphaDataTemplate">
   <Label
       Name="LabelInDataTemplate"
       Content="{Binding}" />
   ```
3. Now in click handler (I would use Commands here), set ContentMsg to whatever you want

   ```
    private void MyButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         ContentMsg = "Bye!";  
    }
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. Your solution is aligned with the best practices for developing, but I guess I have to use both your solution and the aforemention solution from Arun Selve Kumar. That is because in the code that I am developing I need to change the "Visibility" attribute of a "Rectangle" from "Visiblility.Hidden" to "Visibility.Visible" and vice versa.

Comment: That is perfectly fine.. but you can also toggle visibility in MVVM way by using Converters..